# How to set up a echo?

Tags: custom-post-types, conditional-content

My problem is that i don't know how to set up a echo I think. I need it to just wrap a if statement correctly around the code below Please Help...Thanks SO much

```
 <?php 
global $post;
if(get_post_type($post->ID) == 'videos')
{



<video class="video"  width="<?php  echo get_field('width'); ?>" height="<?php  echo get_field('height'); ?>" controls preload>

                        <source src="<?php  echo get_field('mp4'); ?>" media="only screen and (min-device-width: 960px)"></source>

                        <source src="<?php  echo get_field('iphone'); ?>" media="only screen and (max-device-width: 960px)"></source>

                        <source src="<?php  echo get_field('ogv'); ?>"></source>

                    </video>




          <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>

<?php  echo get_field('content'); ?>
}

?>
```

Comment: Please note that purely PHP questions are [not in scope of this site](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq#questions) and probably better asked elsewhere in network (likely Stack Overflow).

Comment: @Rarst His question firstly was about `get_post_type()` then he updated his question with that.

Comment: @rev ah, I missed original. :) user1355485 when you are editing question it often helps to explicitly separate updates as such when they possibly considerably change what question is about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [get_post_type()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_type) function and pass current post id to it.

```
global $post;
if(get_post_type($post->ID) == 'videos')
{
    // do this
}
```

***Update***

```
<?php 
global $post;
if(get_post_type($post->ID) == 'videos')
{
?>
<video class="video"  width="<?php  echo get_field('width'); ?>" height="<?php  echo get_field('height'); ?>" controls preload>

                        <source src="<?php  echo get_field('mp4'); ?>" media="only screen and (min-device-width: 960px)"></source>

                        <source src="<?php  echo get_field('iphone'); ?>" media="only screen and (max-device-width: 960px)"></source>

                        <source src="<?php  echo get_field('ogv'); ?>"></source>

                    </video>

          <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>

<?php  echo get_field('content'); ?>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: The code above has been updated , but still doesnt work.

Comment: @user1355485 in which template u write it?

Comment: single.php i get a Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' I dont't know how to apply the code in php opening and ending tags. I think thats my problem. If i just write the code you gave me it just shows up as text on my site so i need to put <?php  ?> to get it to work, but that doesnt work

Comment: @user1355485 yes, see the update.

Comment: I see. I didn't wrap the php code on both ends. I'm super new to php. So this question must of seemed super noobie. Thanks so much

Comment: I can only check mark one of the answers.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the html tag directly in php tags thats why it's not working properly. I have modified your code as following which is well nested so use the following code.

```
<?php 
global $post;
if(get_post_type($post->ID) == 'videos')
{ ?>
<video class="video"  width="<?php  echo get_field('width'); ?>" height="<?php  echo get_field('height'); ?>" controls preload>

                    <source src="<?php  echo get_field('mp4'); ?>" media="only screen and (min-device-width: 960px)"></source>

                    <source src="<?php  echo get_field('iphone'); ?>" media="only screen and (max-device-width: 960px)"></source>

                    <source src="<?php  echo get_field('ogv'); ?>"></source>

                </video>




      <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>

<?php  echo get_field('content'); ?>
<?php } ?>
```